# What would be a better way to write a loop that loops by initial value

Tags: c++, function, loops

```
    int square(int x) {
    int looptime = x;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i < looptime; ++i) {
        total += looptime;
    }
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        cout << i << '\t' << square(i) << '\n';
}
```

I am new to C++ and trying to learn by self study by reading "Programming Principles and Practices". In this particular problem, I have to make a "square()" function. The catch is I have to use addition,no multiplication.

The above code works and returns correct values, but contrary to mantra of readability, I find it hard to read and understand and I'm the one that wrote it. 
I need to pass into the loop, the initial integer and have it loop that many times without effecting the original amount. Is there a better way to write this.

Comment: I'd suggest also checking out [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `looptime` in the function.

```
int square(int x) {
   int total = 0;
   for (int i=0 ; i < x; ++i) {
      total += x;
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: I started typing out a question to ask you to break the code down as it just wasn't making sense, but as I typed out the questions, I began to understand how I was understanding incorrectly. I added the "looptime" because i was initially getting an infinite loop of doubling that would then overflow and eventually output 0's. Looking at the code again with that in mind, would you have any idea why I may have been getting that in the first place? Thank you though for the help.

Comment: @ButchCrockett, I am not able to visualize the problematic code. If you are able to get your program back to that state, I would suggest creating a new SO post with the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to why it was infinitely doubling, it is difficult without seeing the earlier code. The logical explanation would be that the logic condition in the for loop was flawed, so it never exited when expected.

In this portion, the logic likely would have been where i < looptime is now:

```
 for (int i=0 ; i < looptime; ++i) {
    total += looptime;
```

If that condition is always met, it would explain the symptom (it will remain in the loop, adding to it each cycle). If you can reproduce the earlier result and show the earlier code it would allow this theory to be proven out.

Comment: +1 for attempting to use your psychic powers. It's the first time I've seen a poster ask for help with code they can no longer remember or produce.

Comment: It was not the main question, nor did I expect much, but rather a shot in the dark. I add the "looptime" in after having trouble with what was later given as the solution.@Michael I went back and "undo"ed until I got back to the state that gave me the infinite loop. It turns out i had ">" instead of "<". Thank you.